Sumif times (datetime format) are greater than 22:30
I have an excel worksheet with a column with times&Dates in Timedate format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm) and another with values. I am looking to do a sumif that sums the values if the time (ignoring the date part) is greater or equal to 22:30.
If the datetime is column a and the values are column B i cannt get a sumif(), sum product() or (int) to work

Use FILTER() function filter base on time then sum values. Use MOD() function to separate time from datetime value.
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B1000,MOD(A2:A1000,1)>=TIME(22,30,0)))



It doesn't catch 22:30

@rotabor So, it would be TIME(22,29,59)?

Sure, >TIME(22,29,59).

The original formula works fine for me. I would be surprised if it didn't because 22:30 hours is exactly 15/16 of a day which has an exact representation in binary.

@TomSharpe We shouldn't expect every time constant would be 22:30. Even a multiplier of the power of two. You will be surprised but 22:30 displayed in the table in my answer isn't exactly 22:30. I entered 22:25 then 22:26 and filled the range down. And 22:30 is 80999.98 s not 81000. So, it's very dependent how the numbers are getting in.

@TomSharpe Undoubtedly hope you are familiar with this problematic. So, >TIME(22,29,59) looks like the best solution for >=TIME(22,30,00).

@TomSharpe How big the error in 1m time series? I filled down a range starting at 29/9 22:30. At 101st value the error become greater 0.5 s: { 30.09.2024 00:03:00 179.5100000, 30.09.2024 00:04:00 239.5049999, 30.09.2024 00:04:59 299.4999999, 30.09.2024 00:05:59 359.4949999 }.

Yes, I can see how small errors would add up if you filled the table that way. I think it's one of those cases where we can both be right depending on what assumptions we started with, but your suggestion makes the formula more robust.

The solution for you:

=SUM((A2:A12-INT(A2:A12)>TIME(22,29,59))*B2:B12)

A2:A12-INT(A2:A12) extracts the time part from the timestamp.
Pay attention at time comparison. Due to floating point arithmetic features, comparison should be performed as >TIME(22,29,59) instead of >=TIME(22,30,00).
