Using EOMONTH in Google Sheets considering time not just date
I have A1 showing the start of month (but can be changed)
andI have A2 using EOMONTH(A1;0) to show the last date of that month selected in A1.
In my sheet I use these two cells in various formulas to populate numbers from a report that are within that time frame.
However, I noticed that it doesn't consider records that are from that last date past hour 00:00:00... So basically I need it to show the last day of the month and 23:59:59... How can incorporate this in the formula EOMONTH? It needs to work smoothly based on what start date I pick in A1.

Add time after getting date by EOMONTH(). Try-
=EOMONTH(A1,0)+TIME(23,59,59)


Agree. Although we found that manipulations with times could be subject to rounding errors in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79035973/sumif-times-datetime-format-are-greater-than-2230 so you could add (say) 0.999999 to take make sure of including the worst case scenario of 31/10/24 223:59:59

@TomSharpe Thanks, I will study more on it.

This is the easiest and best solution. Works like a charm. Thank you Harun, once again you helped me a lot.


use these two cells in various formulas to populate numbers from a report that are within that time frame

One solution would be to change those various formulas instead of adding +1 or a proxy like +"23:59:59.999" to the eomonth() result.
So, instead of...
=if(D2 < A2, ...)

...use:
=if(D2 <= A2, ...)

...and so on.
With isbetween(), set upper_value_is_inclusive to true (the default.)
This way, the end dates remain strict dates instead of harder-to-work-with datetime values.

Hey there! My sheet includes various different formulas filtering on the date and I do use <= and >=. I have COUNTIFS and SUMIFS and all sorts of formulas including the date period and they still exclude the last day past hour 0:00:00.
A1 and A2 are my date fields. For example: =COUNTIFS('Report'!$J:$J;$B10;'Report'!$D:$D;">="&$A$1;'Report'!$D:$D;"<="&$A$2)
But it's fine. Harun posted a solution below and it works like a charm. Thanks so much!

That indicates that the values you mention that look like dates are actually datetimes. The time portion may be hidden by the cell format. These offsets happen e.g. when you change the spreadsheet locale. You should check your data.
